# User to resource mapping algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

The problem is simple:
We have n users, numbered 1 .. n
We have m resources, numbered 1 .. m

Asume is no condition/relation between n and m, n < m, n > m, n = m. All are possible. If it makes it really easier, assume n < m.

Each user has a set of k preferred resources, where 1<=k<=m.

Is there any other then brute force, try all combinations, algorithm, that would maximize the amount of users that get served one of their preferred resource, returning a set of pairs User-Resource?

Seems to me that maybe something in Graph theory with bipartite graph, but unsure there.

Harder difficulty:
Try to serve users in order of their ID within a certain limit L. This means user 1 gets served before users 2,3,4,5 .... BUT if total amount of users served would be higher, this can be broken within limit L. ie. Users 2..1+L can be served before user 1, Users x .. x+L can be served before user x-1.,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921583/optimal-placement-of-students I think this is similar

Answer (score 1):

You have a classic problem of maximum bipartite matching. See a longer explanation here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

The relation between n and m is completely irrelevant, the solution will work anyway.

For the harder part:

The traditional solution will try to find a path the in the graph from any node. We don't like that, so change it to iterate from the user id 1 to n and look for a path starting from only the current user. If you don't find a path for a certain start node that's the user with highest priority that you won't be able to serve so take a note and stop when you reach that id + L.

This works because when you are looking for a path you are always increasing the number of connections. So you might reconnect some of the previously established pairs, but you will never disconnect one of the previously connected nodes.